# X11 from macOS 10.15.4 to OracleLinux7 failing

Tags: oracle, macos, x11, oraclelinux

I'm trying to get x11 forwarding working from my mac to an OracleLinux7 box for Oracle setup. Here is the command and errors I'm receiving:

```
ssh -Y user@foo.bar.com
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
Warning: No xauth data; using fake authentication data for X11 forwarding.
debug1: Requesting X11 forwarding with authentication spoofing.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_TERMINAL_VERSION = 3.3.9
debug1: Sending env LC_TERMINAL = iTerm2
debug1: Remote: X11 forwarding disabled in user configuration file.
X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0
```

When trying to run xeyes or xclock

```
[user@foo ~]$ xeyes
Error: Can't open display:
[user@foo ~]$ echo $DISPLAY

[user@foo ~]$
```

Below are the configs for both the mac and linux box:

OL7:
/etc/sshd/sshd_config

```
# Use most defaults for sshd configuration.
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
ClientAliveInterval 180
UseDNS no
UsePAM yes
PrintLastLog no # handled by PAM
PrintMotd no # handled by PAM
TrustedUserCAKeys /etc/ssh/trustedusercakeys.pem
PasswordAuthentication no
X11Forwarding yes
X11UseLocalhost yes
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
```

Mac:
Using xQuartz

```
~/.ssh/config
Host *
  ForwardX11 yes
```

```
echo $DISPLAY
/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.HVJpmjSBkf/org.macosforge.xquartz:0
```

Steps taken to fix:
xauth + on the linux machine returns

```
[user@foo ~]$ xauth
xauth:  file /home/adahlman/.Xauthority does not exist
Using authority file /home/adahlman/.Xauthority
xauth> exit

[user@foo ~]$ xauth +
xauth:  file /home/user/.Xauthority does not exist
xauth: (argv):1:  unknown command "+"
```

I've tried changing various X11Forwarding options to yes and no but still no dice. Any ideas? Could this be a PAM issue?

Comment: Hello Alex, Welcome to StackOverflow. I'm a reviewer of first post and I have following recommandation for you. Can you improve your first sentence so that it contains a verb ! Example: "I'm trying" or something else ...

Comment: Got it working with macOS 10.15.5 + XQuartz 2.8.11, oraclelinux 7.8 + OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips. Config seems similar to yours...